# Find the missing box

Tags: logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

[image]

Can't find any logic here. Can you?

*This question is from the one of high IQ Society founded by Xavier Jouve Ph.D for the top 0.3% of people along the IQ spectrum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be 5?

The outer frame of the 3rd square in the example mirrors the first square in the example's outer frame. Which could mean the 4th should mirror the second, leaving only 5 and 3 as options.

The inner square of each could be considered a moving band of images going down which means the spotty/stripey bit should be in the bottom half in 4, with the stained-glass looking part being out of view. Which leaves 5.

That's the only pattern I can see ‍♂️ But it totally ignores the spacial arrangement of the examples so I can only assume there's more to it.

Comment: I wonder how the tile-shape comes out but now i think maybe this question's purpose is selecting the at least optimal answer... unless someone can tell alternative explanation. Thank you for your answer.